# pacman does not sync core

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman

I run as root `pacman -Syu`
However it just skips right over [core], without prompts, etc.
Just like it was normal to proceed when 0% done.

It just proceeds with extra and community.
How can I force the db to be updated or preferably fix this behaviour?

Comment: post the log, please.

Comment: You should probably start in `/etc/pacman.conf`

Comment: @mikeserv as I said in my answer, this is probably more indicative of a corrupted DB than a configuration problem. good idea, though.

Comment: @strugee - I accept that you're likely right. but if it *was* a misplaced comment or something in there it sure would be easier to fix. So that's where I'd start.

Comment: @mikeserv if it was a misplaced comment, Pacman would have complained at the beginning. not silently failed.

Comment: @strugee - I dunno - the repos are enabled/disabled by default with comments. For instance: `grep testing </etc/pacman.conf` on a vanilla one. I thought that - and possibly this was wrong - that skipping core sounded like a disabled repo.

Comment: @mikeserv no, in that case it would just not print a line for core at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question was a little lacking in details, so I can only answer part of your question. When you post the logs from your terminal, I can answer the rest.

> How can I force the db to be updated?

Passing the `-yy` switch to `pacman` forces it to refresh the DBs from the internet, even if they're not out of date. Use e.g. `pacman -Syyu` to update your system with fresh DBs.

In subsequent comments, you've stated that `pacman` just printed 0%, with a progress bar, and continued on its merry way. This probably means you have a corrupted DB on the local disk. In that case, just do a `pacman` run using `-yy` and you should be fine.

Comment: that fixed it, thanks! Any ideas why it might not have worked?

Comment: @Mark to be honest, since you didn't post your logs, I'm not entirely sure what went wrong in the first place. do you mean it just said `[core] is up to date` or somesuch, or did it just print `[core] [         ] 0%` and move on?

Comment: second version. Maybe I skipped something in setting it up. Doesn't matter aynways now.

Comment: @Mark I've updated the answer. my guess is that you had a corrupt DB, but as you said, it doesn't matter. glad I could help.